# Html Displaying [Object][Object]

Tags: angular, typescript

Okay so I have a an object array that gets sent from an API it shows the index position but I want the object key and value not the index position I think Im mapping the object key wrong can anyone help please

```js
getFav(): void {
  this.Shared.getFav().subscribe(

    data => {
      this.fave = data.message;
      Object.keys(this.fave).map((keyName) => {
        return {id: keyName, product: this.fave[keyName]};
      });
    }
  );
 }
```

```html
<div class="uk-width-small" uk-dropdown>
          <div class="uk-dropdown-grid uk-child-width-1-1@m" uk-grid>
          <div *ngFor="let fav of fave | keyvalue" >
            <span>{{fav.value}}</span>
            <span>{{fav.key}}</span>
      <a href="{{fav.key}}"><li>Buy On amazon<br/>
      </li></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

This is what the Response from My API is so do I have to chnage something on the backend or can I do it on the frontend so it will just show title key and value
[image]

Comment: Where u have added key and value to your fav Object?

Comment: Hi,  title key and value means the title's value at the place of {{fav.value}} and key means "title" at the place of {{fav.key}} ?? or anything else? please explain so, that I can help you

Comment: `fav.value` is an object  ! 
you still have to precise which key you want to be returned maybe : `fav.value.id` or `fav.value.title`

Comment: Okay so fav.key Shows the number of arrays that you see in the second picture 0,1,2,3,4 etc and the value shows the object in the curley braces and what I want to do is access the keyvalue inside that object so the key is title~: and the value is "RUM AWAY"

Comment: Yeah that worked thank you post it as your answer and Ill check it

Comment: no @ConorDonohoe the value isn't RUN AWAY the value is an object that contains "RUN AWAY" as a title so `fav.value.title` would solve ur problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fav.value is an object ! you still have to precise which key you want to be returned 
maybe : fav.value.id or fav.value.title

```
<div class="uk-width-small" uk-dropdown>
    <div class="uk-dropdown-grid uk-child-width-1-1@m" uk-grid>
        <div *ngFor="let fav of fave | keyvalue" >
            <span>{{fav.value.title}}</span>
            <span>{{fav.key}}</span>
            <a href="{{fav.key}}">
                <li>Buy On amazon<br/></li>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the `Object.keys()` on the whole array, which doesn't have any keys, so it just gives you back the indexes and the object. You need to do that for each object in the array for it to work like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

may be you need to change this function `getFav`

```
let newFaves=[]; //declare global var like this on the top of ts file

getFav(): void {
  this.Shared.getFav().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.fave = data.message;
      this.newFaves =this.fave.map((item) => {
        return {id: item.id, product: item.title};
      });
    }
  );
 }
```

then in your html

```
<div class="uk-width-small" uk-dropdown>
          <div class="uk-dropdown-grid uk-child-width-1-1@m" uk-grid>
          <div *ngFor="let fav of newFaves | keyvalue" >
            <span>{{fav.value}}</span>
            <span>{{fav.key}}</span>
      <a href="{{fav.key}}"><li>Buy On amazon<br/>
      </li></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `keyvalue` pipe you dont need to change `getFav`.

value from `keyvalue` is all object `(e.g {id: 20, title: '...', image: '...'})`

so you have to tell angular witch property do you want to use.

```
 <span>{{fav.value.id}}</span>
 <span>{{fav.value.title}}</span>
 <img [src]="fav.value.image"/>
```